# Factor $64x^9 - 125y^6$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, factoring

I'm trying to help my daughter with Algebra 2.  This is a homework assignment.  I've done a fair amount of searching but I just can't figure this out.  Mathway, an online tool gave the answer:

$(4x^3 - 5y^2) (16x^6 + 20x^3y^2 + 25y^4)$

I can pattern match a bit but can't figure out what's going on.  Would someone be willing to provide a link or explain what sort of procedure to follow to factor this expression?

Comment: In general a difference of cubes can be factored as $w^3-v^3=(w-v)(w^2+wv+v^2)$ In your case you have $w=4x^3$ and $v=5y^2$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should see the original expression as the difference of two cubes.  The factorization you have implements $a^3-b^3=(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)$

Answer (score 3):

One starts by observing that $64x^9 - 125y^6 = (4x^3)^3 - (5y^2)^3$.

Answer (score 3):

Way to do this:

$a^3-b^3=(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)$

$64x^9 - 125y^6 = (4x^3)^3 - (5y^2)^3$

$= (4x^3 - 5y^2) [(4x^3)^2 + 4x^3 * 5y^2 + (5y^2)^2]$

$= (4x^3 - 5y^2) (16x^6 + 20x^3y^2 + 25y^4)$